# Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard - Available Tables Empty - issue

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, netbeans

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate into my Netbeans project to connect to Microsoft SQL Server. I've run the Hibernate Configuration file wizard (and set up a new database connection). I've set the dialect to SqlServerDialect. I initially set up the connection with the db_owner schema. I've run test queries on the connection and they all return the correct information.

However, when I try to run either the Hibernate Mapping wizard or the Hibernate Reverse Engineering wizard, there are no available tables to select.

I'm using the JDBC from Microsoft (version 4). There are other similar questions already posted, but no answers that have been provided work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I selected the wrong default schema. I selected `db_owner` and it should have been `dbo`. When I checked the connection under the services tab and expanded the default schema, it showed no tables. Apparently the SQL executor uses other schemas besides the default to find results.